# How to open this update firmware window in kubuntu?

Tags: updates, settings, firmware

In order to update some firmware in my kubuntu 17.10 installation I need to open this window from ubuntu 14.04, however I cannot seem to find it in system settings. If it does not exist, is there an alternative to it?

[image]

Comment: Search the software by its name, of course.

Comment: as far as i know this window comes up when you open System Setting-> Update Drivers in Ubuntu 14.04  i don't think it is a separate program

Comment: There's no such thing is Ubuntu's system settings and never was. This is something Arduino related so something you installed (if you installed, that is) so you should know what.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Googling went me to the [Digi site](http://docs.digi.com/display/XCTU/How-to%3A+Update+the+firmware+of+your+modules).
They have utilities for updating firmware of XCTU (Zigbee) with similar images.

[image: Digi XCTU Zigbee Firmware update program]

So this utility comes from vendor, not from Ubuntu itself.

You can use links on Digi site to get XCTU (do not really know anything about it, just googling).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I was mistaken in assuming that this was Ubuntu related but its is not . For the record this solved my problem.